# Getting PhoneCall null at the time of callDisconnected

Tags: blackberry

Hello Everyone,
           I have implemented PhoneListener to trace Incoming/Outgoing calls.
           I found the demo app from BB support [link](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-the-PhoneListener-interface/ta-p/443044)  & In BB Sample App. (PhoneAPIDemo)

Now I seen some strange behavior, When I write below statement in "**callConnected**" method I am  getting **valid** phoneCall object but when I write below statement in "**callDisconnected**" method I am getting phoneCall object **NULL**.
I checked the callID is same for both method.

```
 PhoneCall phoneCall = Phone.getCall( callId );
```

I am putting the above statement in "callDisconnected" method, because I require Elapsed-time.

```
phoneCall.getElapsedTime()
```

Please let me know why I am getting **phoneCall NULL** & what is the correct way to sort-out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no "Call" to get when call has been disconnected.

Create a phoneCall object as a member variable, initialized it in isConnected() and call  getElapsedTime() in callDisconnected().

public class HelpMario implements PhoneListener {

```
private static PhoneCall phoneCall;

    ....
    ....
    ....

    public void callConnected(int arg0) {

       phoneCall = Phone.getCall(arg0);

     }

    public void callDisconnected(int arg0) {

    //Get Elapsed Time:

            phoneCall.getElapsedTime());
      }
```

}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Buddy for the answer ..now I am following differ approach, I am inserting  callId / CallRecord  in HashTable  (Key/Value) format on call connected event & on call-disconnected event I am removing the key from Hash-table ..this approach is working fine